# not able to install anything using npm in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I am using this in my node terminal

```
C:\Users\Rahul Kumar\Documents\JSProj\app>npm install lodash --save
C:\Users\Rahul Kumar\Documents\JSProj>npm install -g babel
```

Getting this error

```
npm WARN package.json app@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json app@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json app@1.0.0 No README data
```

Comment: Try doing `npm init` and then retry it.

Comment: Those are not errors; they are just warnings about how the `package.json` in your project directory are missing those fields. It will work fine without those fields.

Comment: if you're trying to add dependency modules then use `npm install --save module_name`

Comment: show ur package.json

Comment: Just wait after `npm install` those are just warning it will eventually install all the packages.